# Preventing timing out when using to_sql to connect with SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc

I have a medium sized dataframe with a shape of (749588, 11) that I am trying to save to a table in SQL Server. When I use:

```
sql_members[:1].to_sql('HCC_complete'
               , con=engine
               , if_exists='append'
               , index=False
               , chunksize=10000)
```

It will successfully save the first row to the table and I can see it in SSMS. Even if I use the first [:100] then it will work, but slightly slower.

The problem is when I try to save the whole dataframe I get the following long error:

> OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for
> SQL Server]TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the
> connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
> established connection failed because connected host has failed to
> respond.\r\n (10060) (SQLExecDirectW); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
> 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (10060)')

To me this seems like a timeout issue or some setting in SQL Server. I have tried smaller batches but changing any of the to_sql parameters seem to help. Even `method='multi'` gives me an error about the number of parameters being different. I have no custom query that I am using to save to this table and if I did, why would it work for < 100 rows but not all of them?

After some suggestions I added a connection timeout parameter to my connection `timeout=10000` and `cursor.fast_executemany=True` above my attempt to save the DataFrame to the SQL table.

Comment: Do you have a query timeout set in either your connection string or on the connection?

Comment: Do you use `fast_executemany=True` when creating your engine?

Comment: @SteveFord I don't I'll look into that!

Comment: @AlwaysLearning No, i'll add and update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments I have added `fast_executemany=True` after my engine url which solved the problem. It now looks like:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            f'mssql+pyodbc://@{server_name}/{database}?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server', fast_executemany=True)
```

And it finishes in about a minute.

Comment: this solution didn't work for me